# Ruby - MCollective: how to get the output of a command into a ruby variable (or object)

Tags: ruby, linux, puppet

I hope someone can help me with this one, I am writing a ruby script I have a problem. First the big picture:

when I run from the cli the command:

```
$ mco rpc puppet last_run_summary
```

I get this output:

```
epuppet01.example.com                          
       Changed Resources: 0
   Config Retrieval Time: 1.21247005462646
          Config Version: 1377176819
        Failed Resources: 1
                Last Run: 1377241107
   Out of Sync Resources: 1
          Since Last Run: 195
                 Summary: {"events"=>{"total"=>1, "success"=>0, "failure"=>1},
                           "resources"=>
                            {"scheduled"=>0,
                             "total"=>8,
                             "skipped"=>7,
                             "out_of_sync"=>1,
                             "failed"=>1,
                             "changed"=>0,
                             "failed_to_restart"=>0,
                             "restarted"=>0},
                           "changes"=>{"total"=>0},
                           "version"=>{"config"=>1377176819, "puppet"=>"3.1.1"},
                           "time"=>
                            {"config_retrieval"=>1.21247005462646,
                             "total"=>1.85353105462646,
                             "last_run"=>1377241107,
                             "package"=>0.641061}}
         Total Resources: 8
              Total Time: 1.85353105462646
       Type Distribution: {"Package"=>1}
```

what I want is to redirect/get the output of that command into some variable/object. Specifically I would like to get either the "Failed Resources" part or the "failed" value from the summary.

Any ideas how could a do that??

The code look like this so far:

```
def runSingle
  cmd = []
  cmd.push(which("mco", ["/usr/bin", "/opt/puppet/bin"]))
  shell_command(cmd + ["rpc", "puppet", " last_run_summary", "-I"] + shell_escaped_nodes)
 end
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your code like this:

```
def runSingle
  cmd = []
  cmd.push(which("mco", ["/usr/bin", "/opt/puppet/bin"]))
  cmd_output = shell_command(cmd + ["rpc", "puppet", " last_run_summary", "-I"] + shell_escaped_nodes)
  result = cmd_failure_stats(cmd_output)
  # you'll get 'result' as Ruby hash, like:
  # {
  #   :failed_resources => "1",
  #   :summary_failed => "1"
  # }
  # from which you can access desired values as:
  # result[:failed_resources] #=> "1"
end

def cmd_failure_stats(raw_string)
  return_result = {}
  raw_string.lines.map do |line|
    return_result[:failed_resources] = line[/Failed Resources.*([\d]+)/, 1] if line[/(Failed Resources.*[\d]+)/, 1]
    return_result[:summary_failed] = line[/failed\".*=>([\d]+)/, 1] if line[/failed\".*=>([\d]+)/, 1] }
  end
  return_result
end
```